# How to make text slide in and out of the page

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

I need to achieve same effect as slide in and out effect like on this page :https://pangrampangram.com/products/neue-machina

Comment: There are a heck of a lot of scroll effects and animations on that page. Which one exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @NicolasGoosen the animated letters under section (800px)

Answer (score 0):

create a div inside a another div make the child div bigger than parent div once it get done you can make the child scrolling by left or right attribute in css.

```
`<html data-test-id="brave-new-tab-page" dir="ltr">
```

.parent
        {
            width: 500px;
            height: 100px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .child
        {
            width: 1347px;
            font-size: 76px;
            position: absolute;
        }
    



    
        test test test test test test test tesenter code heret test test
    
    
        let position = 0;
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',  () =>
        {
            setInterval(() =>
            {
                let child = document.getElementsByClassName('child')[0]
                child.setAttribute('style', 'left:-' + position + 'px')

```
            if ( position > ( 1347 - 500 ) )
                position = 0

            position ++
        }, 5)
    }, false);
</script>
```

`

Comment: the animation part of css, what I need to learn

Comment: I have edited my answer. now it is working